# Shared Folder Google Drive Android Api

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I want to create a shared folder in Google Drive Api for android,but  i am unable to find any method as  `.setshared()` using `meta dataset`,it do contains `setstarred` method though.

Comment: Did you see https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert method in Drive API?

Comment: @MichałZiober OP's talking about the [Android (Play Services) API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/) and in particular the [MetadataChangeSet class](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/MetadataChangeSet.Builder.html) not the REST API.